# Problem in evaluating $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(1 - x^2 + x^4)} \ln\left({\frac{x^2}{1 - x^2 + x^4}}\right) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

### Question

How can we evaluate the following integral?

$$
\mathcal{I} = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(1 - x^2 + x^4)} \ln\left({\frac{x^2}{1 - x^2 + x^4}}\right) dx
$$

---

### My attempt

Substituting $x^2 = u \implies 2x \cdot dx = du$ gives:

$$
\mathcal{I} = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1-u+u^2} \ln\left({\frac{u}{1-u+u^2}}\right) \frac{du}{2\sqrt{u}}
$$

Similarly, substituting $\frac{u}{1 - u + u^2} = v$:

$$\frac{1 - u^2}{(1 - u + u^2)^2} \cdot du = dv \implies \frac{du}{1 - u + u^2} = \frac{1 - u + u^2}{1 - u^2} dv$$

So, we have the integral boundaries: from $0 \to \infty$ to $0 \to \lim\limits_{u \to 0} u$. I expressed the new upper limit in limits because the fractional value approaches zero (but not exactly zero) as $v \to 0$ as $u \to \infty$.

This yields:

$$
\mathcal{I} = \int_0^{\lim\limits_{u \to 0} u} \ln v \cdot \frac{1 - u + u^2}{1 - u^2} \cdot \frac{du}{2 \sqrt{u}}
$$

From here, I don't know how to proceed.

---

### Notes to the readers

1. A scientific calculator and integral-calculator.com fails to evaluate this integral.
2. [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+ln%28x%5E2%2F%281-x%5E2%2Bx%5E4%29%29%2F%281-x%5E2%2Bx%5E4%29+dx+from+0+to+infinity) yields -2.17759 ($\pi \ln2$).

Comment: From where do you get the integral(s)? Many of them can already be found here on MSE.

Comment: @Zacky I'm aware of the fact that many advanced problems have already been solved on MSE. However, I try my best to find the available solutions online (if any) before posting questions. To this question, I did not find a solution here.

Comment: I see, here on this site is more useful to use https://approach0.xyz/search/ for searching as it gives better results.// Your question is written better so maybe the mods can merge it into yours.

Comment: @Zacky thanks! Now, I can easily find the existing solutions. By the way, how two questions are merged here?